# How to select pairs of consecutive two data points (which is vehicle type) in the whole data set using R-Programming?

Tags: r

**I have attached a link of excel file with 100 sample**

**Click** [here to download](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ak7BjN7wOe5isnkmm8hbI2Yl8_Ql)!

How to select pair of vehicles in the data set in the following manner?

pairs like:

first: pairs of 2w followed by car

```
          2w
          car
          2w
          car
          2w
          car
          2w
          car
```

Second: pairs of auto followed by 2w

```
          auto
           2w
          auto
           2w
          auto
           2w
          auto
           2w
```

Third: say I want to select pairs of car followed by auto

```
           car
           auto
           car
           auto
           car
           auto
           car
           auto
```

The pair selection would be running along the data set i.e. if one pair is selected in data then the next pair get selected and it goes up to the end of the data set. Until all pairs get selected.

I want to save different pairs of vehicle in a different data frame for further analysis.

**Can anybody suggest what function I have to use in R programming for above   mentioned pair selection.**

Comment: It's much easier if you provide sample data instead of a screen shot and then also show the desired output as typed data.  The easiest method for posting sample data is using `dput`.  If the data set is large then use `dput(head(data.set))`

Comment: I have attached an excel file link. Please find the attachment in the beginning of the post

Comment: This is very hard to read, try formatting it.

Comment: I have reformatted,  now see the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you want:

```
v_type <- 
c("2w", "car", "2w", "2w", "2w", "2w", "2w", "car", "auto", "car", 
  "car", "auto", "car", "2w", "Lcv", "auto", "car", "car", "car", 
  "Lcv", "car", "2w", "2w", "car", "2w", "Lcv", "2w", "car", "2w", 
  "car", "2w", "bus", "car", "2w", "2w", "bus", "2w", "2w", "2w", 
  "lcv", "2w", "2w", "2w", "2w", "2w", "2w", "auto", "2w", "auto", 
  "2w", "2w", "2w", "2w", "2w", "2w", "auto", "car", "2w", "2w", 
  "2w", "2w", "car", "2w", "car", "Lcv", "car", "2w", "2w", "2w", 
  "car", "2w", "2w", "2w", "2w", "2w", "car", "auto", "2w", "2w", 
  "auto", "2w", "2w", "2w", "car", "auto", "bus", "2w", "2w", "2w", 
  "Lcv", "2w", "2w", "car", "auto", "2w", "2w", "2w", "2w", "2w", 
  "2w")
```

Transform the text vector into an integer form of factor and find `diff()` of it:

```
 i <- which(diff(as.integer(factor(v_type))) != 0)
```

at the position `i` the current value differs from the next value.  You can select these by something like

```
cbind(v_type[i], v_type[i+1])
     [,1]   [,2]  
 [1,] "2w"   "car" 
 [2,] "car"  "2w"  
 [3,] "2w"   "car" 
 [4,] "car"  "auto"
 ....
```

If you only need unique such pairs there are several ways, you may consider library "sets".

Comment: Now see the above pair in the question. I want to select like that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.  Can you please: a) create a tiny example dataset (and paste it here using `dput()`); and b) show us the exact form of the desired output on this sample data.